# User policy for a *nix system

Tags: linux, documentation

I would like to create a document that specifies the policies that rule the use of a *nix system from the user perspective, something like TOS (Terms Of Service) / Privacy Policy you find these days on many websites.

Has anyone drafted a document like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of copying and pasting from one of those documents that you mentioned on the "other" sites, I am not sure I understand purpose of your question. If your need is very specific, you will not be able to find a TOS generator to your liking. If your need is generic, as in, don't do anything bad, don't run bots, don't harass others etc, get one of the same from any of the free shell access providers (Google and ye shall find many) and change the names and other relevant information to yours as well as tweaking the wording a bit so that you don't get into copyright trouble. That should be it.

But if your needs are different, you can try to modify your question above, but chances of finding someone who did this and who is/was in the same exact position that you are, is highly unlikely.

Good luck.

PS. I drafted many documents like this while I worked at several of my previous employers but every time, it was something very specific, tailored to my employer's needs.

Comment: Just make sure you leave wiggle room, users can get very lawyerly... and don't go fascist either, always remember that the sysamin is one and the users many. You _are_ in overwhelming numeric inferiority.

Comment: @Mel_Burslan I end up drafting the documents myself, well using wording from other documents and as you said changing the content specific to my needs, thanks.